# How to add another label-like column for a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, function, pandas, iteration, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
id      openPrice       closePrice
1         10.0             13.0
2         20.0             15.0
```

I want to add another column called 'movement':
if openprice < close price set to 1, else set to -1

The output should be this:

```
id      openPrice       closePrice    movement
1         10.0             13.0          1
2         20.0             15.0         -1
```

I can do it in a for loop but it would be time consuming for a df that has more than 10,000,000 rows.

I am new to python and dont know is there any python function can do this in an efficient way.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to fast performance in `pandas` is to use vectorized operations, built-in operations which avoid (as you note) slow Python loops.

My preferred method for giving a sign to changes like this is to call `np.sign` on the difference (having done `import numpy as np` first, of course):

```
>>> df
   id  openPrice  closePrice
0   1         10          13
1   2         20          15
>>> df["movement"] = np.sign(df["closePrice"] - df["openPrice"])
>>> df
   id  openPrice  closePrice  movement
0   1         10          13         1
1   2         20          15        -1
```

One advantage of doing it this way is that you automatically get `movement == 0` if `openPrice == closePrice`, which can be handy.

If you'd prefer to do things more manually, you can do vector arithmetic like

```
>>> df["closePrice"] > df["openPrice"]
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
>>> (df["closePrice"] > df["openPrice"]) * 2 - 1
0    1
1   -1
dtype: int64
```

because here `False == 0` and `True == 1`, but then you'd have to special-case `closePrice == openPrice`.

Comment: Your method scales better than `np.where` for a 20000 row df, `np.sign` takes 971us vs 1.24ms

Comment: Both of you have the desired answer. I really appreciated it. In fact I have a more generalised question. I have a function which takes a couple of column values as input and outputs an value and I wanna apply that function to each row in a dataframe. Is that possible not to use for loop to achieve that? thanks in advance.

Comment: @CrazyGreenHand please post that as a new question, the main thing is to avoit loops but sometimes this cannot be avoided. The general form of applying a function row wise would be something like `df.apply(func, axis=1)` but it depends on your function so I'd post a new question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where` to set the condition for setting a value, the last param is the value for when the condition is `False`:

```
In [6]:

df['movement'] = np.where(df['openPrice'] < df['closePrice'], 1, -1 )
df
Out[6]:
   id  openPrice  closePrice  movement
0   1         10          13         1
1   2         20          15        -1

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```